# Visual Studio Community 2015: High CPU When Idle

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cpu-usage, vs-community-edition

VS Community 2015 uses very high CPU (~50-75 %) if I open a single source file using VS, then close it. This does not occur if I simply start a new VS instance and close the start page (should theoretically be the same state).

I've tried some of the circulating remedies like switching off MS Git support, Enable Browser Link, running in non-admin mode, etc. Nothing works.

Comment: What is your project/file type/language?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov you misunderstood, the problem occurs _AFTER_ I close an individual source file (without loading a solution) of any type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the exact same situation: Because if you open a single file, VS also creates a (temporary) solution. Check this with the Solution manager. This solution is not automatically closed if you close the source file. If you only close the start page, there is no solution.

Seems there is some bug with VS which leads to high CPU consumption if there is an open solution but no open files. If you close the temporary solution, CPU usage will go down. If you have at least one file open, CPU usage will go down.

Comment: I just checked and you are indeed correct sir, thank you. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Seems, this will be fixed in VS2015 update 1 

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1844176/high-cpu-consumption-in-idle-mode

Answer (score 0):

It's early days but Update 2 appears to have fixed the issue around high CPU usage and issues with the devenv.exe process remaining after exit.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx